# Visual Studio can't update packages

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Today, I create a new `Xamarin.Forms` project, in this project, I want to update the packages, see the picture:

[image]

But, I got this error:

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'App37.Android'.

Or you can refer to this picture:

[image]

You also can see many warnings, but I don't care about them. I am only focused on the error.

Comment: The error is most likely because your project's `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` is not set to API 27 or higher which these packages require. Please upload a diagnostic build output as your screenshot only has a warning expanded for it's message. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/android-api-levels/#framework

Comment: Hi ,@JonDouglas. My <TargetFrameworkVersion> is v8.0, to be honestly, I am not familiar with `TargetFrameworkVersion`. So is v8.0 and 27 incompatible?

Comment: @JonDouglas, yes, you are right, 27 is not compatible with v8.0, can you give an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely because your project's `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` is not set to API 27 or higher which these packages require.

Answer (score 1):

The message shows that `App37.dll` (is not found which is the shared project with the Views and Model to share it between iOS, Android and UWP) was not found.

I had a similar issue today (after updating yesterday to Visual Studio 2017 15.6 Update) and removed the reference to the shared project from UWP and Android project, selected the shared library project, did a right click and selected to build it and now I added the library back as reference to the UWP and Android project. Now I was able to compile code again.

Do this and now try to update the NuGet packages.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it, but I remember my VS is 15.6.

Comment: so maybe this is a side effect of the update to 15.6